# Does Shopify Functions Work with Draft Orders? Unable to Disable Coupon Code Application

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I'm attempting to disable the application of coupon codes on draft orders using Shopify functions, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone confirm whether draft orders support Shopify functions or not? I couldn't find any mention of this limitation in the documentation. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

I attempted to create Shopify functions to disable the application of coupon codes on draft orders. However, despite implementing these functions, the desired behavior did not occur when testing with draft orders. I was expecting the coupon code functionality to be disabled as intended, but it seems that the Shopify functions are not having the desired effect on draft orders. Any suggestions or insights into why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I assume you are talking about cart validation function? They do not run on draft order, is the first limitation here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/functions/reference/cart-checkout-validation